# Delete a column from one view but not another

Tags: document-library, column

i want to delete a column in my document library from some of my views but not all of them. How is this done?

Comment: do you want to delete the column or just not show it

Comment: I don't want to show it in some of my views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is modify the views, not delete the column. To do this:

1. Go to your document library and open a view you want to remove the list from.
2. Open the View Menu by clicking the button next to the views that looks like three dots and then select Modify View.
3. Deselect any columns you don't want in the view and click OK to save your changes.
4. Do this for all views you want to change.

You can also follow these steps to add columns to a view. Hope this helps

Comment: I guess this is what I was looking for. thanks brochacho!